# What happens to memory passed in arguments to exec*() family of functions?

Tags: c++, memory, exec

I understand that when calling `exec*()` the memory of the old process is completely replaced with the new program. However, what about the memory of the arguments such as argv?  If I have code like this, is it safe to use memory from C++ data structures such as `std::string` or will these potentially go away, corrupting `argv`?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void
execExample(const std::vector<std::string> &arguments)
{
  char **argv = new char *[arguments.size() + 2];
  char *path = "/path/to/my/executable";
  unsigned int idx = 0;

  argv[idx] = path;

  for (; ++idx < arguments.size() + 1; ) {
    argv[idx] = const_cast<char *>(arguments[idx - 1].c_str());
  }

  argv[idx] = 0;

  execv(path, argv); // Does not return if successful.

  std::cerr << "exec failed: " << strerror(errno) << ".\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`execv` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execv):

> The execv(), execvp(), and execvpe() functions provide an **array of pointers to null-terminated strings** that represent the argument list available to the new program. The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename associated with the file being executed. **The array of pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer**. [Emphasis added]

So, you provide a *null terminated* array of *null terminated* C strings. The man page doesn't explicitly say what happens to the memory, but presumably the strings are copied, as though by a `strcpy`, to the new process, and the new pointers are provided to the `main` of the new process. Because `execv` can't possibly know anything contextual about those strings (are they static? local? `malloc`'d?), it seems unlikely in the extreme to me that the array of pointers would be shallowly copied to the new process

To address your exact question, this means that almost any source of a null-terminated `char*` (including an `std::string`, via `str.c_str()` or `str.data()`) can be used as part of the array passed to `execv`. It's worth noting that, pre C++11, `std::strings` were *not* required to be null-terminated, so long as the `c_str` member returns a pointer to a null-terminated string. I don't know of any implementation of `std::string` which isn't null-terminated, though it's worth noting that, unlike c-strings `std::string`s *may* contain `\0` characters as part of the string data, and not as a terminator.

As a side note, the `execv` call will *instantly* replace the calling process with the new one. This means that C++ destructors *will not be called.* In the case of `std::string`, `std::vector`, and any other dynamic memory, this doesn't matter- all allocated memory is automatically reclaimed, so nothing will leak. However, other side effects won't occur, either- `std::fstream`s won't close their files, etc. Generally this won't ever matter, because destructors with heavy side-effects are poor design practice, but it's something to be aware of.

Answer (score 3):

The strings are copied into the newly-created memory space. So long as they're valid when you call `exec`, you don't have to worry.

Comment: Um right but these arguments are pointers. The question is asking about the validity of the pointees.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit By "the arguments" I mean the logical argument, regardless of how they're implemented. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's handle the simple things first: Because the process image is being replaced, the destructor of the `std::string` will never be called, so the memory does not go away (that way).

I'll assume that you are asking about UNIX-like operating systems because `unistd.h` does not exist on Windows, so the relevant standard is [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html). It is deliberately vague in this area and only states that

> The *argv[]* and *envp[]* arrays of pointers and the strings to which those arrays point shall not be modified by a call to one of the exec functions, except as a consequence of replacing the process image.

What this means is that `exec` shall take care that the arguments are not invalidated by replacing the process image, but that POSIX does not care how `exec` achieves that. This is the bit you can rely on: Your arguments will remain valid and not become corrupted.

As for "in practice:" POSIX does have an idea how implementations did it when the standard was written, and more recent implementations didn't really change the basic mechanism. Let's read a bit between the lines:

> The number of bytes available for the new process' combined argument and environment lists is {ARG_MAX}.

`ARG_MAX` is defined [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html) to a minimum value of 4096.

This requirement makes sense if we assume that there is a fixed-size space (or at least a space that can grow to a fixed maximum size) allocated for arguments and the environment, and that only makes sense if the arguments are copied there before the process image is replaced. POSIX does not *demand* this, but the tacit assumption exists, and indeed this is the way many (perhaps all) systems do it. Moreover, they usually (perhaps always) do it the same way.

Let's have a look at Linux. Take the following two programs `foo`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  char *p = strdup("foobar");
  printf("%p\n", p);

  execl("bar", "bar", p, NULL);
}
```

and `bar`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("%p\n", argv[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Calling `foo` gives me (on x86-64 Linux) the output

```
0x7f6010
0x7fffbefd6ae5
```

Meaning that the string I passed changed location during `exec`. The address

```
0x7fffbefd6ae5
```

sits at the top of the main thread's call stack (which is shifted down a bit from `0x7fffffffffff` by ASLR). What happens on Linux (You can see this with gdb) is that the arguments are copied into this area directly behind one another -- if you call a program with "bar baz qux xyzzy", there will be an area in memory that contains `"bar\0baz\0qux\0xyzzy"` -- then pointers to them are taken and put into a pointer array in the same area, and a pointer to that is passed into main. (The environment is also copied into this area, but that's not part of the question.)

On Linux, this area is allocated along memory page boundaries; up until Linux 2.6.31, it could grow to a maximum of 32 pages (128 KB). Since 2.6.32, the limit is a quarter of the stack size (as determined by ulimit).

Let's have a look at FreeBSD: Using the same programs, the output is (On i386 FreeBSD 9.1):

```
0x28404050
0xbfbfee58
```

Knowing that FreeBSD's stack begins at `0xbfc00000` (no ASLR yet in 9.1), we can see that the same thing happens here. FreeBSD uses a fixed maximum size of 256KB, as does MacOS X. You can find, if you're interested, a fairly long list of historical OS's [here](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/); they all did it essentially the same way. In fact, I do not know a single POSIX-compliant system that does it another way. Such systems could exist in theory; as far as I'm aware, they do not in practice.

Briefly about Windows: It appears to do the same thing; in a couple of tries, `argv[1]` in `bar` lies directly behind `argv[0]`, which lies directly behind `argv` at the top of the stack after `execl`. I was unable to find any documentation of this, but you could say I have empirical evidence that it does not do anything clever, either.